# Why does my insert for new records only does not work even if I'm using where not exits to a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the script I used to create the table.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ODSCustomerBase]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [ODSCustomerBase]
Go
Create Table ODSCustomerBase
(CustomerBaseID             int NOT NULL identity primary key,
RecordSource            nvarchar(4),
RecordType              varchar(2),
SiteURN             nvarchar(128)NOT NULL,
SiteDesc                    nvarchar(60)NULL,
CustomerLink            nvarchar(120)NOT NULL,
HomeCurrencyCode            nvarchar(8)NOT NULL, 
CustomerID                  nvarchar(15)NOT NULL,
CustomerCurrencyCode        nvarchar(8)NOT NULL,
CustomerName            nvarchar(120)NULL,
CustomerShortName           nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
Address             nvarchar(255)NULL,
City                nvarchar(25)NULL,
PostalCode              nvarchar(10) NULL,
CountryCode             nvarchar(3) NOT NULL,
CountryName             nvarchar(60) NOT NULL,
StateCode               nvarchar(8) NULL,
StateName               nvarchar(60) NULL,
Phone               nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
Fax                 nvarchar(30) NULL,
TaxCode             nvarchar(15) NULL,
ProspectID              nvarchar(15) NULL,
CreateDate              datetime NOT NULL,
LastUpdateDate          datetime NULL)
```

This is the script I used to insert records for the **first time**

```
insert into SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase

select 
--Identity as CustomerBaseID
'E4SE' as Recordsource, --could be others, eg 'BST', CRM, nvarchar(4)'
'C' as RecordType, --could be 'p'as prospects, add a case statement
ss.siteURN,
ss.sitedesc,
ss.FS_URL + 'frmcustomer.aspx?CustomerID=' + customerid as CustomerLink,
co.HomeCurrencyCode, 
c.customerid, 
c.currencycode as customercurrencycode,
c.entityname as CustomerName, 
c.entityshortname CustomerShortName, 
c.address, 
c.city, 
c.postalcode, 
c.countrycode, 
cn.countryname, 
c.statecode,
s.statename, 
c.phone,
c.fax, 
c.taxcode, 
c.prospectid,
c.createdate, 
c.lastupdatedate 
from country cn, 
SECSite ss, 
company co, 
customer c 
left outer join state s 
on c.statecode = s.statecode
where  ss.LocalSiteFlag = 1
and cn.countrycode = c.countrycode
```

So if I check the ODS table using this script, it gives me 4395 results

```
use sec_ods
go
select count(*) from  ODSCustomerBase
```

[image]

While this is the script that I use to insert **NEW RECORDS ONLY**. This is where I used the where not exist condition and the sub query which doesn't work because it doubles the number of records. The goal is to insert only new records.

```
insert into SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase

select 
--Identity as CustomerBaseID
'E4SE' as Recordsource, --could be others, eg 'BST', CRM, nvarchar(4)'
'C' as RecordType, --could be 'p'as prospects, add a case statement
ss.siteURN,
ss.sitedesc,
ss.FS_URL + 'frmcustomer.aspx?CustomerID=' + customerid as CustomerLink,
co.HomeCurrencyCode, 
c.customerid, 
c.currencycode,
c.entityname, 
c.entityshortname, 
c.address, 
c.city, 
c.postalcode, 
c.countrycode, 
cn.countryname, 
c.statecode,
s.statename, 
c.phone,
c.fax, 
c.taxcode, 
c.prospectid,
c.createdate, 
c.lastupdatedate 
from country cn, 
SECSite ss, 
company co, 
customer c 
left outer join state s 
on c.statecode = s.statecode
where  ss.LocalSiteFlag = 1
and cn.countrycode = c.countrycode

and not exists(select * from SEC_ODS.dbo.ODSCustomerBase b
                where(Recordsource=b.Recordsource and
                      RecordType=b.RecordType and
                      ss.siteURN=b.siteURN and 
                      ss.sitedesc=b.sitedesc and 
                      ss.FS_URL=b.CustomerLink and 
                      co.HomeCurrencyCode=b.HomeCurrencyCode and 
                      c.customerid=b.customerid and 
                      c.currencycode=b.CustomerCurrencyCode and 
                      c.entityname=b.CustomerName and 
                      c.entityshortname=b.CustomerShortName and 
                      c.address=b.address and 
                      c.city=b.city and 
                      c.postalcode=b.postalcode and 
                      c.countrycode=b.countrycode and 
                      cn.countryname=b.countryname and 
                      c.statecode=b.statecode and 
                      s.statename=b.statename and 
                      c.phone=b.phone and 
                      c.fax=b.fax and 
                      c.taxcode=b.taxcode and 
                      c.prospectid=b.prospectid and 
                      c.createdate=b.createdate and 
                      c.lastupdatedate=b.lastupdatedate))
```

So if I check the ODS table using this script, it gives me **8790** results which is wrong.

```
use sec_ods
go
select count(*) from  ODSCustomerBase
```

[image]

Can someone help me with this please?
Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, one or more of the columns is probably `NULL`.  This will cause the comparisons to fail, so it looks like the records don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use either [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [COALESCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) around all the fields that could be NULL.
e.g. ISNULL(c.address,'') = ISNULL(b.address,'')

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, it didn't work. Do you any suggestion like recreating this whole script? Please look at the new attachment I uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the already inserted data better to go Merge Statment it will just update the existing data or insert the new data

```
MERGE ODSCustomerBase AS T
    USING (
        SELECT Col1,col2,.... FROM ODSCustomerBase

        ) AS S
        ON (
                t.Col1 = s.Col1
                AND t.Col2 = s.Col2
                AND .....

                )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                Col1
                ,Col2
                ,....
                ,....
                )
            VALUES (
                S.Col1
                --,S.NrID
                ,s.Col2
                ,s.Col3

                )
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET T.Col1 = S.Col1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ODSCustomerBase c
            WHERE t.Col1 = Col1

            )
        THEN
            DELETE;
```